# Dimensions Mismatch in julia

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, julia, flux-machine-learning

I'm getting this error:

```
DimensionMismatch("second dimension of A, 1, does not match length of x, 20")
```

for the following code. I'm trying to train a model on some sample `data`. I'm using the `Flux` machine learning library in Julia.

I've checked my dimensions and they seem right to me. What is the problem?

```
using Flux
using Flux: mse

data = [(i,i) for i in 1:20]
x = [i for i in 1:20]
y = [i for i in 1:20]

m = Chain(
 Dense(1, 10, relu),
 Dense(10, 1),
 softmax)

opt = ADAM(params(m))

loss(x, y) = mse(m(x), y)
evalcb = () -> @show(loss(x, y))
accuracy(x, y) = mean(argmax(m(x)) .== argmax(y))

#this line gives the error
Flux.train!(loss, data, opt,cb = throttle(evalcb, 10))
```

Comment: Not super familiar with Flux but it might be easier for people to help if you post the full error message :)

Comment: Your code throws an undefvar error because of  throttle. Could you fix it ?

Answer (score 4):

Your first dense layer has a weight matrix whose size is `10x1`. You can check it as follows:

```
m.layers[1].W
```

So, your data should be size of `1x20` so that you can multiply it with the weights in the chain.

```
x = reshape(x,1,20)
opt = ADAM(params(m))

loss(x, y) = mse(m(x), y)
evalcb = () -> @show(loss(x, y))
accuracy(x, y) = mean(argmax(m(x)) .== argmax(y))

#Now it should work.
Flux.train!(loss, data, opt,cb = Flux.throttle(evalcb, 10))
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. The dimension problem is in `data` since that is what I'm passing to `train!` .

Comment: I tried `data = [( reshape([i],1,1) ,i) for i in 1:20]` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: It is not exactly the same as I explained in my answer. What you did in above is still wrong.